# Can leading coefficients >1 occur in brackets when factorising polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am asked to factorise 2x^2-6x-56.

I find two answers: 1. (2x+8)(x-7) and 2. (2x-14)(x+4).

I am told that the answer is actually 2(x^2-3x-28).

What have I done wrong? Is my mistake leaving a leading coefficient >1 (in both my answers, this being 2) in the brackets?

Comment: This is just convention, there is no right or wrong. All three answers are correct. But to avoid ambiguity (for example in a standardized test) the teacher may require you to have a leading coefficient of 1 for any factor.

Comment: For me, the answer is $2 (x + 4) (x - 7)$, which is the factorization over the integers.

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend, "leading coefficient of 1 for any factor" is not always possible over the integers: $3 x^2 + 7 x + 2=3 x^2 + 7 x + 2$.

Comment: @lhf yes, that's true if we're factoring over the integers, in this case 2 is also irreducible and has to be a factored out if possible. But I was under the impression OP wanted to factor over the reals and in this case factoring out constant terms doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help.